# Itext PDF Image

Tags: c#, pdf, model-view-controller, itext

I am trying to add a signature to the 2nd page of a PDF Form. The PDF was created outside of IText, but it has fields that were populated using IText in C#/MVC. That part works fine.

The issue is getting the signature image to the 2nd page. I can get the image onto the 1st page and position it, but cannot get it to the 2nd page.

I have tried to using the var PdfDocument class' GetPage(x) method without any luck. I have also tried to use GetLastPage(). No luck.

I tried the above approach before flattening the fields and after but no luck.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileSource);
System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(m);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf);
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);

String imageFile = "C:/Temp/signature.png";
ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.Create(imageFile);
Image img = new Image(data);

img.SetFixedPosition(50, 50);

pdf.GetPage(2);
document.Add(img);

form.FlattenFields();
    
document.Close();
pdf.Close();
pdfBytes = m.ToArray();

return new FileContentResult(pdfBytes, "application/pdf");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try hooking up to their event handlers: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-for-net/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers-net

Comment: There is a `SetFixedPosition` overload with an additional first int parameter for the page number...

Comment: Thank you mkl. Your answer has saved me many countless hours of trying to figure this out. Appreciate your reply very much.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it - this will help others...